# Hibernate partial update (How to?)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have a performance problem with a hibernate implementation that is far to performance costly.
I will try to explain my current implementation which must be improved upon with pseudo classes.
Let’s say I have the following POJO classes (the Entity classes are hibernate annotated "copies").

```
Country.java and CountryEntity.java 
City.javaand CityEntity.java 
Inhabitant.javaand InhabitantEntity.java
```

And I want to add a city to a country and save/persist it in the database, the new city arrives fully populated as a POJO.
Current code

```
CountryEntity countryEntity = CountryDao.fetch(someId);
Country country = CountryConverter(countryEnity);
country.getCities.add(newCity);
countryEnity = CountryEntityConverter(country);
CountryDao.save(countryEnity);
```

This results in a major performance problem. Let's say I have 200 cities with 10,000 inhabitants.
For me to add a new city the converter will convert 200 x 10,000 = 2,000,000 inhabitantEntity --> inhabitant --> inhabitantEntity
This puts a tremendous load on the server, as new cities are added often. 
It also feels unnecessary to convert all cities in the country just to persist and connect another one.

I am thinking of creating a light converter which doesn't convert all the fields and only the ones I need for some business logic during the addition of the city, but those will be kept unchanged, I don't know if Hibernate is good enough to handle this scenario.
For example if I save an entity with alot of null fields and the list cities with only one city, can I tell hibernate to merge this together with the db.
Or is there a different approace I can take to solve the performance problem but keeping the POJO and Entitys separate?

Some code below showing my current "slow" implementation code.

```
Country.Java (pseudo code)
 private fields
 private List<City> cities;

City.Java (pseudo code)
 private fields
 private List<Inhabitant> inhabitants;

Inhabitant.Java (pseudo code)
 private fields
```

Currently I fetch a CountryEnity thru a Dao java class.
Then I have converter classes (Entities --> POJO) that sets all fields and initiate all lists.
I also have similar converter classes converting (POJO --> Entities).

```
CountryConverter(countryEntity)
 Country country = new Country();
 Country.setField(countryEntity.getField())
 Loop thru cityEnitites
  Country.getCities.add(CityConverter(cityEntity))
 return country

CityConverter(cityEntity)
 City city = new City()
 city.setField(cityEntity.getField())
 Loop thru inhabitantEnitites
  city.getInhabitants.add(InhabitantConverter(inhabitantEntity))
 return country

InhabitantConverter(inhabitantEntity)
 Inhabitant inhabitant = new Inhabitant()
 inhabitant.setField(inhabitantEntity.getField())
 return inhabitant
```

Thanks in advance /Farmor

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what might be happening is that you don't have an index column on the association, so Hibernate is deleting and then inserting the child collection, as opposed to just adding to or deleting discrete objects to and from the child association.

**If** that is what's going on, you could try adding an `@IndexColumn` annotation to the get method for the child association.  That will then allow Hibernate to perform discrete inserts, updates, and deletes on association records, as opposed to having to delete and then re-insert.  You would then be able to insert the new city and its new inhabitants without having to rebuild everything.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer but I'm not sure I'm following. It's not the deleting or inserting that is the performance thief but rather the iteration of all the inhabitants in the converter.

Comment: Depending on configuration, Hibernate will sometimes delete all members of a child association, and then re-insert them, when all you want to do is add or remove a member.  Is this your situation?  You can tell if you have `show_sql` turned on.

Comment: I don't have show_sql on. However the performance issue I have located is much earlier than when saving or updating thru hibernate. The performance issue is when building a POJO from HibernateEntity thru my converter.
This line is the slow one
   Country country = CountryConverter(countryEnity);
Ofcourse the line is psuedo code as I don't call the constructor.

Comment: Ah, I see.  In your Country entity, set `@BatchSize` on the `getCities` call, then on City, place it on `getInhabitants`.  Right now, Hibernate is running a SELECT for each member of each association.  Setting BatchSize will optimize the fetches using IN.  Use a size which makes sense, like 25 or 50.  You'll see a performance boost.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. But what I would ideally like to do is not to select anything. I mean I am adding a new City to my country, persist it and let the GC remove my Country from the JAVA realm. So I don't want hibernate to read any city at all. Just put my new city in the db and connect it to the country, seems overkill to read up all the inhabitants. I am doing it only because I am afraid if I don't do it hibernate will erase my old country-cities relationship and replace it with only my new city.

Comment: Not sure why you're afraid of that.  If you call `country.getCities().add(mynewcity)`, Hibernate will just add the new City.  It won't delete anything else.  Additionally, you don't want to hold everything in memory.  Only hold what you need.

Comment: Yes but then I have already populated the cities array? I want to do `newCities = new ArrayList<City>();
newCities.add(mynewcity);
country.setCities(newCities)` This is a new array and I am afraid hibernate will se the new array and forget the old. But I wan't it to merge them.

Comment: @Farmor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2578/discussion-between-aaron-sheffey-and-farmor)